# Evaluate the $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ without using calculator?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

> Evaluate the $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ without using calculator?
>
> $150$ degree

the right answer are $\frac{1}{2}$, $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

> $-315$ degree

the right answer are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $1$.

Comment: You may find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up cos and sin on the [unit circle](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html).

[image]

The angles labelled above are those of the special right triangles 30-60-90 and 45-45-90.  Note that -315 ≡ 45 (mod 360).

For tan, use the identity $\tan{\theta} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos \theta}$.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

- Write $150$ as $90 + 60$ and use $\sin(A+B),\cos(A+B),\tan(A+B)$ formulas.
- Write $315$ as $270 + 45$

Answer (score 1):

Two more possibilities:

1. Use a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_tables) of trigonometric values.
2. Use a ruler and a protractor in drawing the line values of the trigonometric functions.  (See, for example, [this](http://www.themathpage.com/atrig/line.htm).)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple.

$\sin(150) = \sin(90+60) = \cos(60)  = \frac{1}{2}$
$\cos(150) = \cos(90+60) = - \sin(60) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
$\tan(150) = \tan(90+60) = - \cot(60) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

**similarly**

$\sin(-315)=-\sin(270+45)=\cos(45) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$\cos(-315)=\cos(315)=\cos(270+45)=\sin(45)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$\tan(-315)=-\tan(270+45)=\cot(45) = 1$

Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicit) for more info on converting trigo identities

Answer (score 1):

I would write $150=180-30$ and use $\cos (180-\theta)=-\cos \theta$ and so on.  Then $-315=45-360$ so it is just the functions at $45$